# Best strategy share data between users on Realm Object Server?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

If I want to share some data between users, what is the best strategy with Realm Object Server. For instance 5 users want to share their favorites movies. Everybody share 3 movies and they should see a list of 15 movies.

Answer (score 1):

If all users share all their favourite movies, they could each have their own realm to write to. You can give all other users read permissions to that realm.
By keeping a reference of all realms(in a realm where everybody has read/write access), a user would load data from all other users and thus see their own and the others' favourite movies.

Comment: "By keeping a reference of all realms(in a realm where everybody has read/write access)". That's mean I have to manage an external table with all the referencies? In addition to Realm I have to use another database?

Comment: You don't have to use another database. I was suggesting you keep use another realm(where everybody has read/write access) to storing the path to each of the users realms with movies. e.g. `/moviesRealmsList` - a list of all users moviesRealms (R/W to all), each user can have its realm with movies `/~/moviesRealm` (R to all, R/W to current user), each user can also have other private realms, for example a list of movies to watch : `/~/toWatch`(R/W to current user)

Comment: I get it, I thought about this solution. The problem is the size o this table. It works for few users. It will be too big for thousand of users.

Comment: Who should create the shared database? any user or the admin?
I've tried to create a Realm without the ~ but I can't see it on the server